# Creating a Member Variable that is Local to a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a server class that creates threads when clients connect. When the client thread is kicked off it just listens to a socket and calls an OnData method when the socket receives data. This is supposed to be a base TCP server class that different classes can inherit in the future. The child classes will only have to override the OnData method.

My question is how do I create a member variable that is local to a thread? I want each thread to have its own state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have each thread be a new instance of your 'ClientThread' class.

That way, each thread gets its own member variables, which can't be accessed by any other thread.

E.g.

```
class ServerClass():
    def make_new_thread(self, state):
        new_thread = ClientThread(state)
        new_thread.start()

class ClientThread(Thread):
    local_state = None

    def __init__(self, state):
        self.local_state = state

    def run(self):
        do_some_stuff()
```

You could then make the class that ServerClass instantiates something that is passed in at run time.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea. I ended up using threading.local() though.

Comment: That's an equally valid way. I figured I'd go for the more general OOP answer so that it can be applied to any language.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an ID to each thread and go from there:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, _id):
        self._id = _id
        setattr(self, '_foo_%s' % str(_id), {'your': 'state'})
```

Now each object has a unique field (if the ID is unique):

```
>>> f1 = foo(1)
>>> f1._foo_1
{'your': 'state'}
>>> f1._foo_2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'foo' object has no attribute '_foo_2'
```

Does that help?